# Origin of "vos" pronoun

Tags: etimología, pronombres, voseo, españa, hispanoamérica

How did the *vos* personal pronoun come to be? Is it etymologically related to *vosotros* in any way? Did it develop before or after the other personal pronouns used today (*tú*, *usted*, *vosotros*, etc)? Was it used in Spain and then transferred to Latin America, or did it develop independently in Latin America?

Answer (score 7):

RAE:

> Forma de 2.ª persona singular [tú] o plural [vosotros].

So what I gather is that `vos` is the short version of `vosotros` **when referring to the second person of plural only**; however, `Vosotros` (vos y otros) is strictly for the second person of plural. RAE again:

> 1. pron. person. Formas de nominativo de 2.ª persona plural en masculino y femenino.

For example:

> Vosotros podéis venir a mi casa cuando queráis => You and the others (your siblings, for example) can come to my house whenever you want.
>
> Vos podés venir a mi casa cuando querás => You can come to my house whenever you want. It refers to only one person (tú/usted/you).

Notice how I removed the `i` from `podéis` and `queráis` above. That really varies by country. A Chilean would say `vos podéis... vos queráis...` however, an Argentinian would say `vos podés... vos querás...`

[This article](http://www.elcastellano.org/ns/edicion/2004/julio/voseo.html) has a good explanation of above:

> A diferencia del pronominal, el voseo verbal no es uniforme para toda
>   América, y se dan tres tipos distintos de voseo: 1) el voseo
>   diptongado, es decir, aquel que conserva las formas cantáis, cantéis,
>   coméis, comáis y partís, partáis; 2) el voseo argentino, es decir,
>   monoptongado en la vocal más abierta del diptongo, y 3) el voseo a la
>   chilena, que conserva diptongadas algunas formas, pero monoptonga
>   otras en la vocal más cerrada, atraído por la tercera.

As far as its origin, [the same article linked above](http://www.elcastellano.org/ns/edicion/2004/julio/voseo.html) says that the use of `vos` can be traced back to the 4th Century.

> En este tema, que, en realidad, es muy amplio, me ceñiré al voseo, o
>   sea, al uso del vos en lugar del tú, que es uno de los fenómenos más
>   característicos del español rioplatense y, también, de los más
>   extendidos y vigentes en casi toda América hispánica.
>
> Hay que remontar el inicio del voseo español al siglo IV de C...

So, to answer your questions:

> Is it etymologically related to vosotros in any way?

Yes, `vos` and `vosotros` come from the Latin `vos`.

> Did it develop before or after the other personal pronouns used today
>   (tú, usted, vosotros, etc)?

After reading the article I linked, I'd say that it was developed after `tú` and `usted`.

> Was it used in Spain and then transferred to Latin America, or did it
>   develop independently in Latin America?

Spain, clearly.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vos#Latin), *vōs* is the plural second-person pronoun in Latin. The Latin *vōs* became the singular second-person *vos* in Spanish, which was then pluralized by appending the *-otros* suffix to form *vosotros* (i.e., *vos y otros*).

The Spanish *tú* comes from *tū*, the singular second-person pronoun in Latin.

A previous question already explained that *usted* comes from [*vuestra merced*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/251/etymology-of-usted).