# ¿Cuál es el significado de "merced" en un contexto de Edad Media?

Tags: significado, español-medieval

Mi pregunta es ésa: ¿Qué es merced?

Hace referencia a "vuestra merced", dicho que se le dice a dos personas, una imaginaria, y a una persona en concreto. Nació fruto de las clases sociales bien definidas en la Edad Media, época en que las personas prácticamente si nacían en una posición social, morían en ella.

**Lo que no entiendo es qué significa Merced. Por lo que entiendo, significa algo como la voluntad, y a la vez el ser de toda persona.**

> Que se haga vuestra merced.
>
> No hay nadie tan fuerte como vuestra merced.

Aclaro que también sé que es un título que se le da a las personas para denotar respeto y no hablarles directamente de tú, o de vos. Justamente se le daba a personas sin un titulo concreto, es como el equivalente en la realeza a "su alteza", "su magnificencia".

Answer (score 9):

Merced significa "gracia". Vuestra merced sería el equivalente en español a "your grace". Se utilizaba para Dios o la realeza, dado el supuesto origen divino de la misma.

Efectivamente, vuestra merced significa más o menos lo mismo que vuestra magnificencia. Vuestra merced se contrajo a Vsted, lo que hoy en día es usted.

Comment: +1 Por descubrirme el origen de _usted_

Comment: ¿Pero cómo se produce el salto de _vuestra merced_ a _v sted_? ¿Se acronimizó?

Comment: @fedorqui estoy seguro que ya tenemos una pregunta sobre el tema, pero efectivamente: *vuestra merçed* -> *vuesamerçed* -> *vuesamçed* -> *vuesançed* -> *vuesasted* -> *vuested* -> *vusted* -> *usted*.  (recuerda que la *Ç* se pronunciaba como /ts/).  Pero no es la única evolución de la forma.  En partes de Colombia (y quizás otras partes de América) existe *sumercé*, de origen quizás mucho más obvio.

Comment: @guifa sí, veo que se preguntó antes: [Etymology of “usted”](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/251/1674), si bien no hay mucho mayor detalle allí. La evolución que detallas tiene bastantes pasos, ciertamente a uno le da que pensar que podría haber evolucionado a muchísimas otras cosas :) Nótese, por lo demás, que en catalán decimos _vostè_: la "d" final en palabras agudas no es muy frecuente y debió caer.

Comment: @fedorqui lo mismo en el asturiano, que dependiendo del dialecto varía entre *vusté/usté*, aunque en el plural reaparece la *d* etimológica: *vustedes/ustedes* (la *d* allí solo se suele conservar entre vocales iguales)

Comment: @walen vueced es simplemente otro camino que acabó incompleto en castellano (pero ojo: se quedó en el portugués *você*).  La evolución no era nada regular ni continua por eso cuando vemos los ejemplos históricos, en un año cualquier se puede encontrar una variedad de formas, algunas que continuaban evolucionando y otros que no.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta requiere que le echemos un vistazo al NTLLE, dado que *merced* no es un término que se use mucho hoy día precisamente, aunque sí que se usaba en el siglo XVII y anteriores.

Así pues, viajemos atrás en el tiempo y veamos qué dice el *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> MERCED. En su riguroso significado, vale el prémio ù galardón que se da por el trabajo, especialmente al jornalero.
>   Significa también dádiva o gracia que los Reyes hacen à sus vasallos, de empleos, dignidades, rentas, &c.
>   Por ampliación significa qualquier beneficio gracioso que se hace à otro, aunque sea de igual à igual. *Yo à lo menos (dixo entonces el Rustico) a la mercéd que me has hecho estare eternamente agradecido.*
>   Vale assimismo voluntád ò arbitrio de otro. *No osaron mas los Moros juntarse: todo era huir, y darse a mercéd del vencedor.*
>   Tratamiento o titulo de cortesia, que se usa con aquellos que no tienen titulo ù grado por donde les toque la Señoria. *Y se acabe la carta, diciendo, Dios guarde a Vueseñoria, ò a vuessa mercéd, o Dios os guarde.*

Nótese esta última definición, que es la que da origen al actual *usted*, dado que implica que se usa para aquellos que no alcanzan determinado grado en la escala social. Según esta definición, *merced* es un tratamiento de cortesía sin especial significado, que sería el usado en tu segundo ejemplo (*no hay nadie tan fuerte como vuestra merced*). Sin embargo, en el primero ejemplo (*que se haga vuestra merced*) el significado es más bien el de "voluntad o arbitrio de otro".

Si vamos más atrás, Covarrubias dice (texto adaptado):

> MERCED, en su genuina significación vale galardón de lo que a uno se le debe por su trabajo: y así llamamos mercenarios a los jornaleros. [...] Merced es una cortesía usada particularmente en España, como en Italia la Señoría, que es común a cualquier hombre honrado [...], que por ser persona que merece ser honrada, la llamamos merced. Mercedes las gracias y las dádivas que los Príncipes hacen a sus vasallos, y las que los señores hacen a sus criados y a otras personas. Finalmente cosa que se da graciosa, se recibe por merced. [...] Darse a merced, es ponerse en manos del enemigo para que él haga su voluntad.

Se ve en el *Covarrubias* ya el uso como tratamiento de cortesía usado para cualquier hombre honrado. También el de sinónimo de "voluntad" en la expresión *darse a merced*. Y me ha encantado descubrir que *mercenario* es aquel que trabaja "para conseguir mercedes" en su sentido original: premio que se da por el trabajo.

Por último, los usos más comunes de *merced* se pueden ver en las siguientes traducciones al inglés del término en un diccionario de 1591:

> Merced, *curtesie, worship, pleasure*.